# How to tell if any jquery dialog happens to be open?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, jquery-ui-dialog

Looking for a general case solution to determine if any jquery dialog (there are multiple) is currently open. Have tried:

```
$(".ui-dialog-content").dialog("isOpen") === true
$(".ui-dialog").dialog("isOpen") == true
$(document).dialog("isOpen") == true
$("*").dialog('isOpen') == true
```

without any success. I expected ".ui-dialog-content" to work, since I can apparently close any open dialog with that selector, but it does not.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

you can try

```
if($(".ui-dialog").is(":visible")){
//dialog is open
}
```

Comment: Something must be really odd with the styles on this page then. In firebug console while a dialog is open: $('.ui-dialog').is("visible") == false

Comment: @lamont - note the colon in front of `:visible` - it's a psuedo-selector.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery UI dailog has a method `isOpen` which returns true if the dailog is open. Call it on the element which has opened the dialog box.

```
$('.ui-dialog-content').dialog("isOpen");
```

Refrence: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#method-isOpen

Comment: see my question - $('.ui-dialog-content').dialog("isOpen") returns false while a dialog is open.

Comment: tried this - only works for the first dialog in the class.  You'd need to use `.each()` to check for _any_ dialog.

Comment: I think that should have taken care by dialog to run each loop internally.

Answer (score 1):

According to the API documentation, you should use

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog( "isOpen" )
```

to determine whether the dialog is open or not. The function returns a boolean.
For example,

```
if( $("selector").dialog("isOpen")===true ){
     /*do stuff when dialog is open*/
} else {
     /*do stuff when dialog is closed*/
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if it's being displayed or not via CSS?  Not sure if it's the right approach, but I suspect it'll work.

```
$(".ui-dialog").css('display') != "none"
```

Comment: EDIT: actually $(".ui-dialog-content").css('display') != "none" gives a false positive if the dialog is closed, but does return true when it's open, while ".ui-dialog" seems to be always false.

Comment: >>> $(".ui-dialog-content").css('display')
"block"
>>> $(".ui-dialog").css('display')
"none"

regardless of dialog state, in firefox at least.

Comment: yeah it was a shot in the dark, I haven't used ui-dialog, was going off my general knowledge, looks like you found your answer though so that's great!

Answer (score -1):

```
$('html').click(function() {
    x++;
    if(x==2){
    $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").trigger("click");
    x=0;
    }
    });
```

This one will work in all cases, where you call Dialog from DOM.

Comment: Not answering the qtn