# Jquery UI dialog cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'isOpen'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I use my code as bellow.   The function get_devcies_full is call ever 5times if the dialog opens already Don't opent it again just update the content  Then i will code Bellow i the got the error in javascript

> cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; 
>   attempted to call method **isOpen**

```
function get_devcies_full(id,slno)
{
    $.post("user/get_full_device/" +id + "/" +slno,
        function(data) {
            var NewDialog = $('<div id="MenuDialog"></div>');
            if (NewDialog.dialog( "isOpen" )!==true){
                NewDialog.dialog({
                    modal: true,
                    title: "Title",
                    width :940,
                    height:600,
                }); 
            }
            NewDialog.html(data);
            var t = setTimeout(function () {get_devcies_full(id,slno);},5000);
        }
    );
}
```

Please give solution where i got problem?

Comment: Your question title is not self explanatory and there is no explanation to the problem you are facing in your description.

Comment: You probably mean to make your first line: `var NewDialog = $("#MenuDialog");`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function get_devcies_full(id,slno)
{
    $.post("user/get_full_device/" +id + "/" +slno,
        function(data) {
            if(!($("#MenuDialog").length))//if this div created for first time
            {
                $(body).append('<div id="MenuDialog"></div>');//First time you have to append this in body  
            }
            if (!$('#MenuDialog').dialog('isOpen'))
            //Try if not works => if(!($("#MenuDialog").parents(".ui-dialog").is(":visible")))
            {
                $("#MenuDialog").dialog({
                    modal: true,
                    title: "Title",
                    width :940,
                    height:600    
                });
            }
            $("#MenuDialog").html(data);
            var t = setTimeout(function () {get_devcies_full(id,slno);},5000);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method isOpen

Comment: May this url will help you https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/jquery-ui/EQ-doOGDRrE

Comment: Try the above answer which I have changed. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130564/how-to-tell-if-any-jquery-dialog-happens-to-be-open